# MVC - Rendering a static HTML page that refers to other static resources

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, articulate-storyline

I have created a project in an application called 'Articulate' that publishes as a file/folder structure of html pages and resources like images, videos, etc.  Aside from MVC, you would normally just upload it to your server and be done.

In MVC, I'm trying to understand the best way to accomplish the following:

**1)** Put this published output in a folder in my MVC web project - as is - without going in to re-write the published html output 'Articulate' produces.

**2)** Allow the html pages to refer to resources in this embedded file/folder structure (other html pages in the structure, images, videos, etc.)

**3)** Be able to render a page in a way similar to an iframe, so that if it reloads or forwards to another page, it does so only within the rendered area, such as a div/modal.

I have seen a couple similar posts that didn't pan out or didn't match all my criteria above.

Comment: As it stands, this question is too vague to answer. 1) Do you have any need to use MVC other than organizing the project? 2) Do you need these html pages to link to MVC URLs or MVC to link to these pages? 3) What is wrong with creating a few dynamic MVC views rather than creating a lot of static html files? A view can do everything a static HTML file can do and more.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I have a full MVC application and just want to integrate in this Articulate project output, which is a file/folder structure of html pages, images, etc.).  The whole point is to use the output of this Articulate project in my MVC application without going in and re-writing all of the html/javascript, etc. created by their publishing output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research of approaches, the only way I found to meet all of my needs was to create a partial view and within it put an iframe.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src="~/StaticFolder/staticPage.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer text-right" style="padding-right: 75px; margin-left: 0;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="CancelModal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

This approach maintains all referential links inside the html pages and allows me full control over calling the partial with an MVC structure.